# Can you edit /etc/passwd on a firmware image?

Tags: linux, passwd

I'm trying to gain root access on a cheap DVR that I bought for a CCTV system. The manufacturer has a firmware update image available for download that I was able to inspect using a tool called `binwalk` and I extracted the rootfs. It looks like a flavor of embedded Linux with Busybox.

I took a look at the `/etc/passwd` file and it has one line for `root` with a password hash and a login shell defined. There's no `/etc/shadow` file but there is a `/etc/passwd-` which I haven't seen before.

I also found an init script that would normally be launching `telnetd` but it's commented out.

Can I just generate a new password hash to substitute in `/etc/passwd`, uncomment the `telnetd` line and then log in as root with the new password through telnet over the network?

(Of course this is ignoring the possible problems I could run into with flashing the new firmware onto the device and bricking it)

Edit:

Here is the output from binwalk. It's a U-Boot image containing a JFFS2 filesystem.

```
Target File:   /vagrant/rootfs-3531dv100
MD5 Checksum:  18a010179a1e5ae03c260ccc9609ddbc
Signatures:    404

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xCB1642A1, created: 2019-09-26 01:53:07, image size: 9761796 bytes, Data Address: 0x0, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0x35F26A52, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: Filesystem Image, compression type: none, image name: "hirootfs"
64            0x40            JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
```

Comment: I would suggest to try cracking the hash with a tool like https://crackstation.net/ , john the ripper or something like this before reflashing

Comment: Dissappointed that this question has drawn close votes "needs clarity" and a down vote without commenting as to what is unclear.

Comment: @jvergeldedios It's unclear from what you've written what type of image this is. I would suspect it's a [squashfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS).  Theoretically you can unpack it, modify it then re-pack a new squashfs image.  This may be complex as sometimes multiple images can be packed into a single file.  I assume you used `binwalk --extract ...`.  Could you [edit] your question to include the output from binwalk please.  This may give some information we can work with.  *No guarantees*.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Updated above. I guess the ambiguity in my question may come from whether I'm asking _generally_ if you can edit the /etc/passwd file and have things work or if I'm asking if it will work in my _specific_ situation. I'm more curious in the general case since this is a Unix forum and not a reverse engineering one. Would updating the question to reflect that help?

Comment: So theoretically you can.  You can extract the u-boot image which is just a wrapper to get the underlying JFFS2 file system.  Then you can mount the JFFS2 file system, edit it, unmount it and finally re-pack it into a new u-boot image.  I was going to write up an answer to that effect.  Only JFFS2 is so hideous to mount, I don't want to advise you to do it without *understanding* the madness it requires.

Comment: For the Uboot-tools wrapper you can get the [u-boot-tools](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/u-boot-tools) package and use `dumpimage` and `mkimage`.  That will give you a file with just the JFFS2 image.  I'm afraid mounting that is going to be a lot of work on google.

Comment: For mounting, [this might be helpful.](https://wiki.emacinc.com/wiki/Mounting_JFFS2_Images_on_a_Linux_PC)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just generate a new password hash to substitute in /etc/passwd, uncomment the telnetd line and then log in as root with the new password through telnet over the network?

Maybe! It depends on what else the vendor may or may not have done. In general, it could be just that easy... *if* you can capture, mount & edit the firmware image, re-flash it, and there is no checksum or signature elsewhere that the firmware image must match.

Since you did not specify the make and model of the DVR, there is no way to give a sure answer. But in principle, your idea seems reasonable.

> There's no `/etc/shadow` file but there is a `/etc/passwd-` which I haven't seen before.

`/etc/passwd-` is typically a backup of the `/etc/passwd` file, created by the standard commands like `passwd`, `useradd`/`userdel`/`usermod`, etc. The convention to name the backups of user/group files (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, later also `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/gshadow`) like that is just one of those "ancient Unix history" things: at some point, the convention was established, and after that it was easier and more compatible to keep following the same practice than changing it without a compelling reason.